# Unable Render HTML content with vanilla JS components

Tags: javascript

Trying to write some JS to better understand components and rendering content to the page. In the following JS I am initializing a function menu and then trying to call in inside my App method. However, the browser is stating 'Cannot access menu before initializaiton'. How can I go about rendering the content from the menu method? Thank you.

JS:

```
const root = document.getElementById('root')

const Welcome = () => {
    return `Welcome to my Javascript Program!`
}

const App = () => {
    return `
        ${menu(true)}
        <h1>${Welcome()}<h1>
        <div> I EXIST! </div>
    `
}

const render = root => {
    root.innerHTML = App()
}

render(root)

const menu = (show) => 
{
  if (render) {
    return 
    ` <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
            <li>Login</li>
        </ul>
    </nav> `
  } 
 return `<nav>Menu</nav>`
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: *'Cannot access menu before initializaiton'* because `menu` here is a variable storing a function and not an ordinary function declaration, so it doesn't get hoisted to top of the script, so you need to declare it at the beginning of your script or just before you use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const root = document.getElementById('root')

const menu = (show) => {
  if (show) {
    return (
      ` <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
            <li>Login</li>
        </ul>
    </nav> `);
  }
  return `<nav>Menu</nav>`
}


const Welcome = () => {
  return `Welcome to my Javascript Program!`
}

const App = () => {
  return `
        ${menu(true)}
        <h1>${Welcome()}<h1>
        <div> I EXIST! </div>
    `
}

const render = root => {
  root.innerHTML = App()
}

render(root)
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

If you type `return` in a line with nothing that follows, JS will assume that you want to early-exit out of the function (because the semi-colon is optional in JS), and will actually return `undefined`.

Your problem is here:

```
const menu = (show) => 
{
  if (render) {
    return                 // this is the culprit
    ` <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
            <li>Login</li>
        </ul>
    </nav> `
  } 
 return `<nav>Menu</nav>`
}
```

Your `return` is followed by a new line. In javascript, that is a valid statement.

Also, the boolean you pass into `menu()` is sometimes called `show` and in the function body you named it `render`. Choose a single name, since `render` is a reference to another function in your code, so that will always be evaluated to truthy, regardless of what boolean value you pass into `menu()`.

```
const menu = (show) => 
{
  if (show) {   // fix the parameter name from render to show
    return (     // JS will unserstand that you need more lines...
    ` <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
            <li>Login</li>
        </ul>
    </nav> `);     // closing here...
  } 
 return `<nav>Menu</nav>`
}
```

Comment: That's only part of problem. Error thrown is due to hoisting. Also think it should be `if(show)`

Comment: Thank you charlietfl. Good explanation and tips especially regarding the return statement. It now works.